# How to perform call sequence to a REST API in Android App?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, reactivex

I'm having a hard time making a call to my api. I'm using Reactivex with kotlin and Flowables. My API returns a list of items if the date I passed by the "If-Modified_since" header is less than the last update. 
If there is no update I get as an app return android app a 304 error.

I need to do the following procedure.
1-> I make a call to the api
2-> If the call is successful, save the list in Realm and return to the viewmodel
3-> If the error is 304, I perform a cache search (Realm) of the items
4-> If it is another error, I return the error normally for the ViewModel

Here is the code below, but I'm not sure if it's that way.

```
override fun getTickets(eventId: String): Flowable<List<Ticket>> {
        return factory
                .retrieveRemoteDataStore()
                .getTickets(eventId)
                .map {
                    saveTickets(it)
                    it
                }.onErrorResumeNext { t: Throwable ->
                    if (t is HttpException && t.response().code() == 304) {
                        factory.retrieveCacheDataStore().getTickets(eventId)
                    } else
                        //Should return error
                }
```

The question is, what is the best way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume, that you're using Retrofit. If that's the case, then you could wrap your getTickets call in `Single<Response<SomeModel>>`. This way, on first map you can check the errorcode, something among the lines of:

```
...getTickets(id)
  .map{ response -> 
        when {
response.isSuccessful && response.body!=null -> {
                                         saveTickets(it)
                                         it
} 
!response.isSuccessful && response.errorCode() == 304 -> {
factory.retrieveCacheDataStore().getTickets(eventId)
}
else -> throw IOException()
}
}
```

This could of course be made pretty using standard/extension functions but wanted to keep it simple for readability purposes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Exactly, I'm using retrofit. I was running a call and waiting for a Flowable.
`@GET("api/web/events/{event_id}/get-tickets")
 fun getTickets(@Header("If-Modified-Since") date: String,
                        @Path("event_id") eventId: String): Flowable<List<Ticket>>`

Answer (score 0):

Most of my comments are my explanations.

```
data class Ticket(val id:Int) { 
     companion object { 
         fun toListFrom(jsonObject: JSONObject): TICKETS { 
             /**do your parsing of data transformation here */
             return emptyList()
         }
     }
}

typealias TICKETS = List<Ticket>


class ExampleViewModel(): ViewModel() {

    private var error: BehaviorSubject<Throwable> = BehaviorSubject.create()
    private var tickets: BehaviorSubject<TICKETS> = BehaviorSubject.create()

    /**public interfaces that your activity or fragment talk to*/
    fun error(): Observable<Throwable> = this.error 
    fun tickets(): Observable<TICKETS> = this.tickets

    fun start() {

        fetch("http://api.something.com/v1/tickets/")
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .onErrorResumeNext { t: Throwable -> 
                    if (t.message == "304") {
                        get(3)
                    } else {
                        this.error.onNext(t)
                        /** this makes the chain completed gracefuly without executing flatMap or any other operations*/
                        Observable.empty()
                    }
                }
                .flatMap(this::insertToRealm)
                .subscribe(this.tickets)

    }

    private fun insertToRealm(tickets: TICKETS) : Observable<TICKETS> {
        /**any logic here is mainly to help you save into Realm**/
        /** I think realm has the option to ignore items that are already in the db*/
        return Observable.empty()
    }

    private fun get(id: Int): Observable<TICKETS> {
        /**any logic here is mainly to help you fetch from your cache**/
        return Observable.empty()
    }

    private fun fetch(apiRoute: String): Observable<TICKETS> {
        /**
         * boilerplate code 
           wether you're using Retrofit or Okhttp, that's the logic you 
           should try to have 
         * */
        val status: Int = 0
        val rawResponse = ""
        val error: Throwable? = null 

        val jsonResponse = JSONObject(rawResponse)
        return Observable.defer {
           if (status == 200) {
               Observable.just(Ticket.toListFrom(jsonResponse))
           }
            else if (status == 304) {
               Observable.error<TICKETS>(Throwable("304"))          
            }
            else {
                Observable.error<TICKETS>(error)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        this.error = BehaviorSubject.create()
        this.tickets = BehaviorSubject.create()
    }

}
```